# preg_match() to match either of the given condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

yesterday I got some help here to get the regular expression right to accept the input such as,

```
Plymouth, United Kingdom
```

but I realised that I should accept such input below as well,

```
Plymouth, Devon, United Kingdom
```

so I added another expression in the code below and now it cannot accept either of the condition above! what have I done wrong?

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$/', $mem_town_city_country) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{2,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$/', $mem_town_city_country))
{
    $error = true;
    echo '<error elementid="mem_town_city_country" message="TOWN/CITY, COUNTRY - sorry, they appear to be incorrect."/>';
}
```

how can I make it to accept the input either

```
Plymouth, United Kingdom
```

**or,**

```
Plymouth, Devon, United Kingdom
```

?

Comment: Describe the whole task. What input do you expect to be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `||` to `&&`. The current code will show the error message if *either* the first regex or the second regex is not matched. You want the error message to show only if *both* regexes do not match.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$/', $mem_town_city_country) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{2,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$/', $mem_town_city_country))
```

Alternatively, you can use regex alternation to combine the two:

```
if(!preg_match('/(^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$|^[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{2,}[\,]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$)/', $mem_town_city_country))
```

Of course, it's possible to shorten this, but in the above code sample I am trying to show the concept rather than making the code as concise as possible

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the one regex, that do all the work:

```
$input = 'Plymouth, Devon, United Kingdom';
$matched = preg_match('~^[a-z\s]{4,}(?:,[a-z\s]{4,}){1,2}$~i', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matched, $matches);
```